# How to access elements correctly in own defined type in F#

Tags: f#

I'm just starting to learn F# and am confused with this school assignment. Please excuse me if this is a dumb question, I couldn't find the answer by searching. The assignment wants me to:

The set of *complex numbers* is the set of pairs of real numbers.

Define a type `complex`  that represents complex numbers with floating point components.

Define a function `mkComplex : float -> float -> complex` that given two floating point
numbers return the corresponding complex number.

Define a function `complexToPair : complex -> float * float` that given a complex number *(a,b)*
 returns the pair (a, b) .

Here's my attempt at this:
first I define the type `complex`:

```
type Complex = float * float
```

I define the function `mkComplex`:

```
let mkComplex a b = Complex (a, b)
```

The function `complexToPair` is the one giving me trouble. How do I given the complex type access the elements inside it correctly? the following works runs fine but I am getting spammed with typecheck errors.

```
let complexToPair (a: Complex) = (a.[0], a.[1])
```

`a.[0]` and `a.[1]` is underlined in red and giving me the following warning:

The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints.

So, what am I doing wrong? The code works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type definition that you are using is defining a type alias. When you say:

```
type Complex = float * float
```

Then the type `Complex` is just a tuple. You can create its values using `(1.0, 1.0)`. When you have a value `c` of this type, you can access elements using `fst c` and `snd c`, or by using pattern matching.

Using a type alias is sometimes useful, but I guess that, in this case, it would be more desirable to use a single-case discriminated union or a record, i.e.:

```
type Complex = { a:float; b:float }       // Using a record
type Complex = Complex of float * float   // Using a discriminated union
```

The [documentation on F# records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records) explains everything you need to know about using records. For single-case discriminated unions, you can refer to [an article in the Desinging with Types series](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/) at F# for Fun and Profit.